# Crear columnas en un dataframe a partir de otra que tiene registros tipo diccionario

Tags: python

tengo un df que tiene una columna llamada tags que tiene en sus datos una estructura como `{'is':false, 'is_not':false}` y a partir de esa columna o sea tags quiero sacar dos columnas una llamada `is` y la otra `is_not`.. existe alguna manera de sacar esto directo o tengo que hacer un for? lo estoy haciendo algo asi  `df['is']=df.tags[0]['is']` pero de esa manera todo los registros quedarían con los valores del primer registro... alguien me puede ayudar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

Puedes utilizar `apply(pd.Series)` para separar el diccionario en varias columnas

Cree un `dataframe` sencillo para mostrar el ejemplo:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3], 'b':[{'is':'false', 'is_not':'false'}, {'is':'false', 'is_not':'true'}, {'is':'true', 'is_not':'true'}]})
```

El `dataframe` que se crea es:

```
    a   b
0   1   {'is': 'false', 'is_not': 'false'}
1   2   {'is': 'false', 'is_not': 'true'}
2   3   {'is': 'true', 'is_not': 'true'}
```

Luego utilizamos `apply(pd.Series)` en la columna `b`

```
df['b'].apply(pd.Series)
```

Esto devuelve lo siguiente:

```
    is      is_not
0   false   false
1   false   true
2   true    true
```

Si quieres eliminar la columna `b` y en su lugar poner las columnas recien creadas puedes utilizar el método `concat()`:

```
pd.concat([df.drop(['b'], axis=1), df['b'].apply(pd.Series)], axis=1)
```

Esto devuelve lo siguiente:

```
    a   is      is_not
0   1   false   false
1   2   false   true
2   3   true    true
```